# How to use solution-level configuration to dynamically change SSIS package OLEDB connection in design time

Tags: configuration, ssis, connection-string

I am modifying an SSIS project that our company took over from another vendor. I can see that for the existing projects, when I change the solution configuration, all the OLEDB connection server names are changed. Specifically, if I change the solution configuration from "production" to "staging", all the connections change from production server to staging server.

I can't figure out how this is done. I've been searching MSDN, Google, etc. for some time, and all the posts point me to the package configuration, but that is not what the project is doing, because all the existing packages have the option "Enable package configurations" turned off.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is your Connection Manager ConnectionString property configured through a User defined variable? Here is how to check: Opposite click MyConnectionManager > Properties > Expand Expressions > ConnectionString > @[User::MyConnectionString]

Comment: Thanks for replying!My connection managers for the OLEDB connections are all using shared data sources defined for the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I think you are seeing Visual Studio Configurations at work.  These can store a discrete version of each Data Source's connection string definition (in the .dwproj file). Visual Studio magically swaps these in and out as you change the Configuration selection.

This is not related to the package configuration, which will actually override whatever you see in the Visual Studio UI at runtime. This can be very confusing.